# How to get the index of the subviews of scrollview which are stored in an array on touching the subviews?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

The base view is a scroll view. In the scroll view, I have multiple web views as subviews which are stored in an array on adding. On touching a specific web-view I want the index of the web view being touch. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[NSArray indexOfObject:]` to find the index of the web view in your array.

while adding you `UIWebView` and add a tap gesture to each one and assign a tap responder. In the responder you can check for `indexOfObject`.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set `tag` for `UIWebView` to index value of array while adding objects.

Comment: I did that. Moreover, I have customized the scroll view so that the touches event can be fired. Now, the problem is when I am touching a particular subview,the condition (touch.view == v) is never true in the following code.

Comment: -(void)customScrollViewTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{  
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    for (MyView *v in [MYScrollView subviews])
    { if([v isKindOfClass:[MyView class]])
        { if (touch.view == v)
            {for(int k=0; k<MyArray.count; k++)
                { UIView *view = [MyArray objectAtIndex:k];
                    if(touch.view.tag == view.tag)
                    {NSLog(@"View with tag %d touched",view.tag);
 } }  } }  }  }